# setNeedsDisplay not firing DrawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

I have a viewController which is obviously a subclass of `UIViewController` called `MapViewController`. In this viewController I use GPS to get the location of the user.

I also have a view called `DrawCircle`. This view is a subclass of `UIView`.

Using drawCircle I would like to be able to at any time draw on my MapViewController. But I am not sure I am understanding the concept of doing so. I know my drawing code is working, I have used it before. But I don't know how to draw onto `MapViewController` using `DrawCircle`.

From what it seems to my whenever I call `[myCustomView setNeedsDisplay]`, it is not calling the `DrawRect` method in my view.

Here is some code:
**MapViewController.h**

```
#import "DrawCircle.h"


@interface MapViewController: UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    DrawCircle *circleView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) DrawCircle *circleView;
@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "DrawCircle.h"

@interface MapViewController ()
@end

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize circleView;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    circleView = [[DrawCircle alloc] init];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

**DrawCircle.m**

```
#import "DrawCircle.h"

@interface DrawCircle() 
@end

@implementation DrawCircle

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


      CGPoint point = CGPointMake(40, 137);
      CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 10, 10));
    }

    CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor redColor] CGColor]));
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

Also if this offers any help into my thought process, here is my StoryBoard scene.
[image: StoryBoard Scene]

Where the viewcontrollers custom class is MapViewController and the views custom class is DrawCircle.

**EDIT:**I would also like to mention that, in my DrawCircle.m, I have methods that I am calling from MapViewController.m and are working.

Also. Initially, the DrawRect method is being called but I am not able to manually call using `setNeedsUpdate`. When debugging, it is not even entering the DrawRect method.

Comment: By the way, while I hope my answer below helps, your comment about maps and GPS makes me wonder what kind of Map you're using. If you're using `MKMapView` and if you want this view to be associated with lat/long coordinates, there are much better ways of accomplishing that (e.g. custom annotation or `MKCircle` overlay). But if you want this red circle to float in space, not moving as the user pans and zooms the map, then your custom view is fine. Just depends upon what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating your DrawCircle, but you're never adding it to the view, e.g.

```
[self.view addSubview:circleView];
```

Therefore, it's falling out of scope and (if using ARC) getting released on you. You also don't appear to be setting its `frame`, such as:

```
circleView = [[DrawCircle alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Alternatively, you could add the view in interface builder (a standard `UIView`, but then specify your custom class right in IB).

Also, note, you generally don't even to call `setNeedsDisplay`. The adding it to the view hierarchy will call this for you. You only need to call this if you need to update the view based upon some custom property.

---

Personally, I'd be inclined to define `drawRect` like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // I'd just use `rect` and I can then use the `frame` to coordinate location and size of the circle

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);

    // perhaps slightly simpler way of setting the color

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);

    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

This way, the location and size of the circle will be dictated by the `frame` I set for the circle (by the way, I apologize if this makes it more confusing, but I use a different class name, `CircleView`, as I like to have `View` in the name of my `UIView` subclasses).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *circle;

    circle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 200.0)];
    circle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // because it calls `super drawRect` I can now enjoy standard UIView features like this
    [self.view addSubview:circle];

    circle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300.0, 300.0, 10.0, 10.0)];
    circle.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // because it calls `super drawRect` I can now enjoy standard UIView features like this
    [self.view addSubview:circle];
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Rob! This definately solved my issue with being able to update my view! The only issue that arose now is that, even though I set my circlView to the size of my mainviews bounds, it is only sized to half the screen, its not currently full screen.

Comment: @JohnnyWhisman is the circle that's drawn too small? Or is the view itself too small? I let, for example, the background color for the circle view and see, unambiguously, where it is, but then make the drawing of the circle take up the whole frame. I also refrain from hard coding sizes, but rather let the process of setting the frame control the size. See update. Beyond that, it's hard to say why you're not seeing the full circle without updated code sample, but the above is working for me.

Comment: @JohnnyWhisman I hope my updated answer with code samples doesn't make it more confusing. It's just I like my custom views to behave like standard `UIView`/`UIImageView` where the `frame` defines the location and size of the control. But if you have other needs of your `DrawCircle` class, where maybe it's drawing a bunch of circles and animating them and the like, then having the circle not take up the whole `frame` makes sense. It just depends upon what your goal is. Still, adjusting background colors can help diagnose what's going on, separating `frame` problems from `drawRect` problems.

Comment: My circles where completely fine. I do draw multiple circles. It seems as though the circleView is about half the size of the screen. So I am only able to draw circles on half of the screen. I do hardcode the sizes, because I only (and always will only) be drawing circles of the same size.

Comment: I also am probably making it confusing in the fact that, I don't have a view for each circle. I have a view that I want the size of the screen, to draaw the circles on. Again, thank you so much for your help Rob.

Comment: @JohnnyWhisman - No problem. I'm sure you'll figure it out now. If there's anything else I can help you with, let me know. But without a more complete, updated code sample, it's hard to diagnose why you're seeing them on only half of the screen. Nonetheless, good luck.

Comment: Thanks rob. One last question. I set the size of my circleView to [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]. I also changed the color from clearColor to black, just to see if it was taking up the full screen. Even with this, it is about 3quarters of the screen. I am sure I will be able to figure it out though. You have definitely pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyWhisman A couple of random thoughts: 1. I'm not crazy about using applicationFrame; not at 0,0 and doesn't reflect nav bars, tab bars, etc.; 2. I prefer view.bounds; 3. try deferring until viewDidAppear; 4. try plain UIView and make sure it's not some problem hidden in your class; 5. pause in debugger and enter po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription] in console at (lldb) prompt and see what it says; 6. Have initWithFrame NSLog the string, NSStringFromCGRect(frame); 7. try setting autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: You are awesome. I hadn't had a chance to update this thread yet, but I went with step 3 and it works perfectly. I can't thank you enough :)